# behaviour of std::async(std::launch::deferred) + std::future::then

Tags: c++, concurrency, c++17, stdasync, std-future

The idea behind a deferred future (achieved only by calling `std::async` with `std::launch::deferred` flag) is that the callback is called only when someone tries to wait or to pull the futuristic value or exception of the future. by then the callback isn't executed.

What happens if I attach a continuation to a deferred future with `std::future::then`? the deferred future is lost (`then` invalidates the future) and a new future is returned instead.

In this case, according to the standard, what should happen? is the new future is a deferred future as well? would it just deadlock? this question is not addressed in the latest documentation.

Comment: An older draft spec (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3721.pdf ) mentions: **If the parent has a policy of launch::deferred and the continuation does not have a specified
launch policy or scheduler, then the parent is filled by immediately calling .wait(), and the policy of the antecedent is launch::deferred**

Comment: However I can't find this anymore in a newer revision http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0159r0.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This, in my opinion, seems to be a bug in [the TS](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0159r0.html#futures.unique_future).  Or at least an underdocumented trap.

Here is the text from the TS:

## 2.3 [futures.unique_future]/6-10

> ```
> template <class F>
> see below then(F&& func);
> ```
>
> Requires:
>
> ```
> INVOKE(DECAY_COPY (std::forward<F>(func)), std::move(*this)) shall be a valid expression.
> ```
>
> Effects:
>
> The function creates a shared state that is associated with the returned future object. Additionally,
>
> When the object's shared state is ready, the continuation `INVOKE(DECAY_COPY(std::forward<F>(func)), std::move(*this))` is called on an unspecified thread of execution with the call to `DECAY_COPY()` being evaluated in the thread that called then.
>
> Any value returned from the continuation is stored as the result in the shared state of the resulting future. Any exception propagated from the execution of the continuation is stored as the exceptional result in the shared state of the resulting future.
>
> Returns:
>
> When `result_of_t<decay_t<F>(future<R>)>` is `future<R2>`, for some type R2, the function returns `future<R2>`. Otherwise, the function returns `future<result_of_t<decay_t<F>(future<R>)>>`. [ Note: The rule above is referred to as implicit unwrapping. Without this rule, the return type of then taking a callable returning a `future<R>` would have been `future<future<R>>`. This rule avoids such nested future objects. The type of `f2` below is `future<int>` and not `future<future<int>>`:
>
> [ Example:
>
> ```
> future<int> f1 = g();
> future<int> f2 = f1.then([](future<int> f) {
>                     future<int> f3 = h();
>                     return f3;
>                  });
> ```
>
> — end example ]
>
> — end note ]
>
> Postconditions:
>
> `valid() == false` on the original future. `valid() == true` on the future returned from then. [ Note: In case of implicit unwrapping, the validity of the future returned from thenfunc cannot be established until after the completion of the continuation. If it is not valid, the resulting future becomes ready with an exception of type `std::future_error`, with an error condition of `std::future_errc::broken_promise`. — end note ]

There is no special case for a deferred future task.  If that deferred future task is not ready before calling `.then`, there is no way for it to become ready, so there is no way for the decayed copy of `func` to be invoked.

The text for `shared_future` is similar; there, you can still cause the `shared_future` to become ready after calling `.then` however.

If this is intended; that `.then` on a not-ready deferred unique future will result in a return value of a `future` that can never be made ready -- this should be explicit in the TS/standard.  If this is not intended, the standard text needs to be changed.

Note that these changes do not appear in the [N4762 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/n4762.pdf) published in 2018.

I am not sure how the standard should fix this; the `.then` semantics are reasonable for a `shared_future` but not for a `future`, and differing semantics would be surprising.